# More on the Feynman Path Integral Formula  in Brian Cox' Lecture and its Consequences

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

This is a continuation of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22373/2451) about Brian Cox' lecture *Night with the Stars.*

I know the main steps to get from $K(q",q',T)=\sum_{paths}Ae^{iS(q",q',T)/h}$ to $\Delta t > \dfrac{m(\Delta x)^2}{h}$ as stated below, but can you expand? (just read below)

PART 1

The action function $S(q",q',T)$ is given by $ S = \displaystyle\int dt\left( \dfrac{1}{2} m v^2 -U\right)$. For a classical path that goes uniformly from one point to the other you have $v = \dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ and so you get $S \propto m \left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2\Delta t=m\dfrac{(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta t}$. What are the processes and steps taken to you get to $S \propto m \left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2\Delta t=m\dfrac{(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta t}$? (explained clearly please).

PART 2

$S/h$ appears as a complex phase term. To make it small we set $S/h < 1$, and we can then deduce that $\Delta t > \dfrac{m(\Delta x)^2}{h}$.

What are the processes and steps taken to then get to $\Delta t > \dfrac{m(\Delta x)^2}{h}$?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in this the -U from the first equation is ignored and when I say how to get to the next step I mean in the sense that for example: "$x+5=8$ , $x=3$".......but rather "$x+5=8$ , minus 5 both sides $x=3$

Comment: So basically I need an explanation as to the mathematics done that got to the next step in the formulas

Comment: I don't understand how you can take S/h<1 when you have assumed semi-classicality with v = delta x/delta t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part 1:

Let's say the velocity in the integral is constant in time, and the integral is from 0 to $\Delta t$. We now have a trivial integral of a constant. So (ignoring U)

$$
S = \int_0^{\Delta t} \frac{1}{2}mv^2\ dt\\
=\left[\frac{1}{2}mv^2t\right]_{t=0}^{t=\Delta t}\\
=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\Delta t
$$

So, substituting $v = \dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, and ignoring any constants we have before them, except for mass, we get

$$
S \propto mv^2 \Delta t\\
  \propto m\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2 \Delta t\\
  \propto m\frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t}
$$

So $S \propto m \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t}$ as required.

Part 2:

We have

$$
S \propto m \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t}
$$, so then, saying the constant of proportionality is $k$, and that it is approximately 1 (we'll want this not to be huge in a minute), we get

$$
S = k m \frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t}
$$

Now, setting $S/h < 1$, we get

$$
\frac{S}{h} = k m \frac{\Delta x^2}{h \Delta t} < 1
$$

Setting $k = 1$, we can now say

$$
m \frac{\Delta x^2}{h \Delta t} < 1
\Rightarrow m \frac{\Delta x^2}{h} < \Delta t
$$
as required.

Comment: when you're at the stage of $$\propto m\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2 \Delta t\\$$ what happened to $\Delta t$ at the end of the equation to get you to $\propto m\frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t}$?

Comment: Also, at $\frac{S}{h} = k m \frac{\Delta x^2}{h \Delta t} < 1$, why can you just add Planck's Constant, h, into the equation?

Comment: And how is your resultant $\frac{\Delta x^2}{h} < 1$ the same as my $\Delta t$ > $\frac{m(\Delta x)^2}{h}$

Comment: When answering the 3 questions, label the answer to the first comment '1', the second comment '2' and the third comment '3' please. Thanks

Comment: Comment 1: $m(\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t})^2 \Delta t = m \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t^2} \Delta t$. The $\Delta t$ on the left cancels out the $\Delta t$ under the line.

Comment: Comment 2: Since you've divided both sides of the equation by the same number, they're still equal. You then say this new number is less than 1, because of the inequality you had before.

Comment: Comment 3: Typo. Fixed it. That line was just multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\Delta t$.